# User Defaults saves data in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

I'm currently creating a sprite kit game in Xcode, as part of the progression system I need to store a single mutable array of integers in the user defaults. The code I'm using works just fine on the simulator, however when I load it onto my iPhone 5 it does not save or load the array.

When I run the code on the simulator I have the log list the value at each index whenever it is loaded, saved or changed, and it works fine. On the phone however it acts like the array is empty or does not exist and lists no values.

**Here is my code:**
**In the header file**

NSMutableArray*  saveData;

**In the implementation file**

This initialises the array in the didMoveToView method

```
saveData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
```

This is also used in the didMoveToView method, it updates the visual game progress interface I am using with the saved values.

```
-(int)loadSaveData:(int)i{
    return  [[saveData objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}
```

This is called whenever there is a touch on a specific node in order to update the array ready to be saved again later. Also lists the array values.

```
-(void)setSaveData:(int)i :(float)j{
    [saveData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:j] atIndexedSubscript:i];
    NSLog(@"Set index %i as %f",i,j);
    [saveData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Object %lu is %@", (unsigned long)idx, obj);
    }];
}
```

Saves the array, called in the willMoveFromView method. Also Lists the array values.

```
-(IBAction)saveProgress:(id)sender{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:saveData forKey:@"progress"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [saveData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Object %lu is %@", (unsigned long)idx, obj);
    }];
    NSLog(@"saved");
}
```

Loads the saved array and lists the values. This is called in the didMoveToView method directly after the saveData array is initialised.

```
-(IBAction)loadProgress:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"loading");
    saveData = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"progress"] mutableCopy];
    [saveData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Object %lu is %@", (unsigned long)idx, obj);
    }];
}
```

As I said before the enumeratesObjectsUsingBlock just isn't called when running on the phone, but is fine in the simulator. The app doesn't crash at all, the values are just not loaded or saved.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am still new to this and any information is good information.

Comment: You say you declare `NSMutableArray* saveData;` in your implementation file. Where? In a global scope?

Comment: Yes, it is a global variable, declared below the interface - end section.

Answer (score 0):

Check `saveData` variable in `saveProgress:` - it might be `nil`.

You can change your `loadProgress:` method to initialise array at first load:

```
-(IBAction)loadProgress:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"loading");
    saveData = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"progress"] mutableCopy];
    if (!saveData) {
       saveData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];        
    }

    [saveData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Object %lu is %@", (unsigned long)idx, obj);
    }];
}
```

Comment: It turns out saveData is nil in saveProgress, why would this be? It's already been defined and initiated as a global variable?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately the problem persists. It does seem to be an error with saveData being declared and defined, but I really thought that would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated in your comment that you are declaring the variable in the global name space in the .h file. As such, you are not declaring one global variable, but a different instance every place where the .h is included. The compiler then decides which instance you will get, which explains why it works in the simulator, but not in the device.

You need to use an `extern` declaration.

In the Header (.h) file:

```
extern NSMutableArray *saveData;
```

In the .m file:

```
NSMutableArray *saveData = nil; // Always explicitly initialize to nil
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem, it really does look like the saveData array isn't being defined or declared properly, I wish I could provide more information but there's nothing more to say as far as I'm aware.